Curvature of geodesic spheres
Suppose $\mathbb{R}^d$ is given a Riemannian metric $g$. Fix a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^d$, fix two tangent vectors $v,w \in T_p \mathbb{R}^d$ with $\langle v, w \rangle_g = 0$, and consider the function $c_t(s) = \exp_p( t[ (\cos s) v + (\sin s) w ] )$, where $\exp$ is the exponential map induced by the metric $g$. It is possible to obtain a control on $c_t'(0)$ using the theory of Jacobi fields / Rauch comparison type techniques, and one has $|c_t'(0)| \lesssim t$. Is it also possible to obtain a bound of the form $|c_t''(0)| \lesssim t$ for small $t$? The motivation here is studying the curvature of the 'geodesic spheres'
$$ S_p(t) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d: d_g(p,x) = t \} $$
when $t$ is small.

Yes. The idea is that the second fundamental form of the geodesic sphere satisfies a Riccati equation, which can be studied using comparison theorems. The curvature tensor of the geodesic sphere can be written in terms of the second fundamental form and the curvature tensor of the ambient space. This is known as the Gauss equations. This is all explained in Eschenburg, Comparison theorems and hypersurfaces, Manuscripta Math.59(1987)  295–323.
